# Why does inheritation of ArgumentParser cause TypeError when adding subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

Why is the following code causing troubles?

Intention: I want to extract common options and sanitization code between argument parser of tools in a tool-suite.
Edit: I want to add additional arguments to the constructor.

```py
import argparse

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def parse_args(self):
        return super().parse_args()

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = MyParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    subparsers.add_parser("create", help="Create something...")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom-argparser.py", line 13, in <module>
    subparsers.add_parser("create", help="Create something...")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\argparse.py", line 1123, in add_parser
    parser = self._parser_class(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prog'
```

Comment: You don't need to override `__init__` and `parse_args` if you don't want to change their behaviours. You can just inherit the ones from the superclass.

Comment: @khelwood this is just a minimal example. I want to add behaviour to the default ones

Comment: OK. In that case you need to support the arguments that will be passed to `__init__`.

Comment: The subparser creator passes a custom `prog` value to the parser class.  This is used in subparser's usage message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change your `__init__` input params

Update your code to as follows

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
```

New Update:

Second simplest option is not define `__init__` as it would just inherit its parents definition.

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def parse_args(self):
        return super().parse_args()
```

This is a **preferred option** and reason is, while redefining  `__init__` you would need to understand all the default & key word arguments you would receive at you custom class level and then you need to understand and pass them to `super().__init__()`.

In case you want some additional params to be included then defining `__init__` is a standard method generally follow. Otherwise, keep it simple

Comment: You should pass the args and kwargs (at least the required ones) to the super init as well

Comment: @NirO - Yes. During this test case, it was working fine, so I left it out ! Let the update the description more. Thank you.